# Scaling WGS84 coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, scale, proj4js

I know this is a weird question, but I would like to know if it is possible to construct a proj4 string so that I can use proj4 to convert from WGS84 to a "scaled" WGS84 system. For example with a scaling factor of 10000, the coordinates 52.123456, 12.525643 would become 521234.56, 125256.43.

Comment: You could change the units from degrees to ten-thousandths of degrees.

Comment: That's an idea, but how would I go about to do that?